# After uploading a file, I want to close that file pop up from where the file was selected in protractor

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, protractor

The file I want to upload is added on attach document field but this pop up is not closing.

**My Code is:**

```
var path = require('path');
var fileToUpload = 'C:/Users/r/project photos/11182717-Business-woman--Stock-Photo-lawyer.jpg',
absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);  element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/a/i')).click();     
element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is *not to open the popup* (assuming we are talking about the "Choose file" browser popup). Remove this line containing the "click" action:

```
element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/a/i')).click();
```